# How to use JSON to return array from a query?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to display all of the continents but all I am getting is '[object Object]' instead of the actual continent names. How can I actually get the continent names to show?

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.get('auto.php',{act:'fetchContinent'},loadContinents ,'json');

$("select#continents").change(function(){        
             $('div#display').html($("select#continents option:selected").text())});

function loadContinents(data){
          var optionStr = "";
          for (var index in data) {
              optionStr += '<option value="' + data[index] + '">' + data[index] + '</option>\n';
          }
          $("select#continents").html(optionStr);}                           
});
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: @TommyTopas I don't understand how to use that

Comment: please, post your ajax call also

Comment: does it throw any error?

Comment: can we also see the result html (select)?

Comment: @TommyTopas no, just just shows [object Object]

Comment: wait a sec, what does the returned array from php contains?

Comment: the returned array contains 0: {Continent: "Asia"}
1: {Continent: "Europe"}
2: {Continent: "North America"}
3: {Continent: "Africa"}
4: {Continent: "Oceania"}
5: {Continent: "South America"}
6: {Continent: "Antarctica"}

Comment: please edit your question and insert your last comment, to better define the data that you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `[object Object]` because the array returned from the server contains objects! Since those are in the form `{Continent: "thecontinent"}`, you can write the option like this:

```
optionStr += '<option value="' + data[index].Continent + '">' + data[index].Continent + '</option>\n';
```

> *data[index]* is the object {Continent: "thecontinent"}
>   *data[index].Continent* is the value of the Continent property ot that object